# Syntax error, unexpected '|'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting the syntax error in my Rails 4 Ruby 2 app, but I can't understand why. I think it's happening on line 10.

```
<% ('A'..'Z').each do |i| %>
            <h2><%= i.capitalize %></h2>
            <hr class="half-rule">

            <% lesson_num = [] %>
            <% start_id = 0 %>
            <% last_id = current_user.last_lesson %>
            <% until start_id >= last_id do |x| %>
                    <% lesson_num << [x]%>
                    <% x += 1 %>
            <% end %>

            <% lesson_num.each do |id| %>
                    <% lesson = Lesson.find(id) %>
                    <% tags = @lesson.tags.split(',') %>

                    <% tags.each_with_index do |tag, index| %>
                        <% letter = tag.initial %>
                        <% if letter == i %>
                            <a href="/lesson/<%= id %>/step/1"><%= tag %></a>
                        <% else %>
                        <!-- else is only necessary if you actually need to put something here.-->
                        <% end %>

                    <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: What is the syntax of an `until`-loop in Ruby? And what inside that loop changes anything that would alter truthiness of the loop's condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not writing the `until` loop correctly; it does not `yield` any elements so the `|x|` is not appropriate here.

Also, you probably mean to increment `start_id` or else your conditional for the loop will never evaluate to `true`.

Lastly, you are shoveling arrays (`[x]`) into the array `lesson_num`. You probably don't want to do this since you later iterate over `lesson_num` and use each element as an `:id` for a row in the Lesson table.

Try something like:

```
        <% lesson_num = [] %>
        <% start_id = 0 %>
        <% last_id = current_user.last_lesson %>
        <% until start_id >= last_id  do %>
                <% start_id += 1 %>
                <% lesson_num << start_id %>
        <% end %>
```

I have written this so that `start_id` will increment first, and then be added to `lesson_num`. This way a zero will not end up in the array and you will not later try to look up `Lesson.find(0)` which will give you at the least a `nil` value or some other problems.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

At first glance, I attacked your problem directly. But after viewing the suggestion by Jay Mitchell and reflecting a little bit there seems to be a more concise solution here that will eliminate a lot of logic in your view (Yay!) and be more readable. (Yay!)

Since all you really need is to count from 1 (or maybe 0) up to `current_user.last_lesson`, you can use the range `(1..current_user.last_lesson)` to create the array you need. Then you can iterate over this in your view:

```
<% (1..current_user.last_lesson).each do |id| %>
  <% lesson = Lesson.find(id) %>
```

What you may benefit from even further is to set up relationships between your models, since it appears that each user has many lessons and each lesson belongs to a user. This will grant you easier and more efficient ways to access a users lessons and iterate over them. (i.e. something like `users.lessons.each do |lesson| ... end`)

Comment: That simplification is huge! Thanks so much. It's working perfectly, and I'll probably try to tackle setting up the associations like you recommend later.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby [`until`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) statements don't pass a parameter to the block, so the `|x|` on line 8 is invalid.

One option would be to replace the `until` with `(0..current_user.last_lession).each do |x|`.